# Cron command to delete Magento 2 captcha images

Tags: magento2, cron, captcha, magento-cron

my *pub/media/captcha/base* directory of Magento 2 has over 500k images!

This causes the server's inodes to become overloaded.

So I know that these images would be deleted every 10 minutes, but this don't work for me.

I search for a cron command to delete these captcha images... Can you help me please?

Thanks!

P.S: I've red other related posts but I can't find any working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to see which is the cron identifier if you install https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2 and run the command `n98-magerun sys:cron:list`. Obviously, the cron should have something related to deleting expired captcha in the name.

Once you found the identifier, you can execute it individually by running `n98-magerun sys:cron:run <identifier>`.

Good luck!

---

***LE***

The related crons can be executed like this:

```sh
n98-magerun sys:cron:run captcha_delete_expired_images
n98-magerun sys:cron:run captcha_delete_old_attempts
```

without the n98 tool, you are not able to run an individual cron command on its own outside Magento's cron management (which you mentioned is not working for you? check this also https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html maybe there is some misconfiguration somewhere).

Comment: Hi Diana, thank you for the reply!
Unfortunately I'm not an expert so for me it's difficult to follow your advice. 
I search for a simple cron command that I can add to my cPanel cron jobs in order to delete that images every XX minutes.
Can you tell me how to build this command, please?

Regards

Comment: I updated my answer above, please check it out.